# How to fetch the post content from the wordpress editor before it can be saved(published)?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-editor

Please excuse me if I sound lame, I am newbie to wordpress plugin development and I have a requirement where I need to fetch the data from the editor before it is being published. 
Also, along with the data, I want to get the values of few customized options which I am yet to add (checkboxes or radio button). I have explored about `get_the_content()` and `wp_editor()`, but it doesn't seem to help.

If it not possible to fetch the data before publishing, what are my alternatives? All I need from the editor is the post data and the values of those custom options.
Please do let me know if my question isn't clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the post data before publishing the post for reviewing it or to do some processing before the post gets published?

Comment: If you want to do something with the data while the user is on the WP editor screen/page you might need to do it with Javascript to manipulate the DOM, Otherwise WordPress has filters and Hooks for that too if data processing needs to be done on server side.

Comment: Yes @kabiir, exactly I want to fetch the post content in the editor itself and I have processing to be done on the server side. So, I would be obliged if you could guide me through the name of the filters and hooks used to fetch this data.